# Pre-calc complex roots $7$-th root of unity help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

Let $\omega$ be a complex number such that $\omega^7 = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1$. Let $\alpha = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4$ and $\beta = \omega^3 + \omega^5 + \omega^6$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic
[$x^2 + px + q = 0$]for some integers $p$ and $q$. Find the ordered pair $(p,q)$.
I have already found that p = 1, correct me if I'm wrong. How do I find q?

Comment: Isn't $p=-1$.?.

Comment: @Nosrati  don't think so  because w+w^2+w^3+w^4+w^5+w^6 = -1. So, then the sum of the roots of the quadratic are -p. p=1

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: A generalization of this question with $\omega^n=1$ might be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $\,\alpha\beta=\omega^4(1+\omega+\omega^3)(1+\omega^2+\omega^3)=\omega^4(\omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + 3 \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1)\,$, then use the first step.

Comment: how would you solve for the 3w^3

Comment: Thanks @dxiv, you just plug in q and you get p=1, q =2

Comment: @ilikepi314 Correct, since $\omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + 3 \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 2 \omega^3$.